# is my iphone spying on my macbook?

Tags: macos, ios, security, bluetooth

The Bluetooth indicator in the Macbook's menu bar is indicating a connection, but does not list a connected device in the Bluetooth preferences. `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType` shows it is my iPhone running services:

`PAN Network Access Profile, AVRCP Device, Handsfree Gateway, Audio Source, MAP MAS-iOS, Wireless iAP, AVRCP Device, Phonebook`

There is no indication of any bluetooth connection in the iphone's bluetooth menu, and i never asked it to do any of this.

What's going on?  Is it possible this is malware?

Comment: I believe having two Apple devices on a single iCloud account kind of "pairs" them. I noticed this the other day on my Mac where it said my bluetooth mouse was paired as so was my iPhone 5s. However I don't think this is anything you should worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is normal.your devices won't actually use this e.g. for bt file exchange but when using services/features like continuity/handoff etc you will see they are somehow connected (transferring data).if both of your devices have the same iCloud account, then this is it.no need to worry.